# Do I even need to submit my app to Facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook

I hate Facebook so freaking much.  I have been developing an app for 2 years and they have screwed me so bad by discontinuing their codes.

All I need are the user_friends permission.  I do not want single sign in.  I can't submit my app because there is red on the submission form because I can't add iOS as a platform.  I heard this was because single sign in was not checked, but it is checked even though I don't want it.  Still no dice.

The first junk of red was from the first submission where we were trying to use taggable_friends and got rejected.

[image]

I think everything is here that needs to be:

BUT I CANT ADD A PLATFORM

[image]

My main question is why can't I add a platform?  What the hell is all this shit?  What is app center?  Why can't I submit my app?

Why is the first image directing me to the App Center Guidelines.  Is my app missing something for App Center.  I really don't care about app center.

Answer (score 0):

On the left on developers.facebook.com if you have created an app you should see **Settings** - click that, then there is a large column width button "+ Add Platform" near the bottom.